# dynamically get results from exec

Tags: php

I have a php script that calls a go script. It gets results every 1-2 seconds, and print's them. Using php's `exec` and `output`, I only get the results when the program finishes. Is there a way I can check the output to see when it changes and output that while it's still running?

Something like this, but pausing the execution?:

```
$return_status = 0;
$output = [];
$old_output = ["SOMETHING ELSE"];
while ($return_status == 0) {
  exec($my_program,$output,$return_status); #somehow pause this?
  if $output != $old_output {
    echo($output);
    $old_output = $output;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use the [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) function to get a file handle for the command's output, then read from it a line at a time.

Comment: can you please add an example?

Comment: Read the documentation. There are several examples in there.